# Plugging in headphones does not mute speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio

My speakers are working even when I plug in my headphone to the front jacks. So I hear sounds from both headphones *and* speakers. This is quite annoying.

How could I fix this? What could cause this problem?

I'm using Realtek HD Audio Manager 6.0.1.6392 in Windows 7. My motherboard is a [Sapphire Tech PI-AM3RS785G](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?cid=2&gid=361&sgid=588&pid=278&psn=&lid=1&leg=0).

Comment: What make and model is your laptop? (msinfo32 will show you)

Comment: @kinokijuf I added my mainboard model info. I am using desktop

Comment: First off, make sure your headphone plug is not undersized.  Try using a headphone extension to get a different plug.

Answer (score 13):

I have been looking over and over for the answer and keep getting information that has to do with buttons and options I don't have on my computer or steps that were just missing. Here is what I found.

Press Start.

Press Control Panel on the right side.
*(If it took you to Control Panel > All Control Panel Items; Press on Control Panel in the address bar at the top)*

Press Hardware and Sound

Press Sound

This should give you a dialog box labeled Sound with 4 tabs labeled Playback, Recording, Sound and Communications.

While under the Playback tab; Plug in and Unplug your headset while looking for the Speakers that are going from Not plugged in to Ready. Click on the Speakers once you figure out which one it is.

Press Set Default at the bottom

Press Apply

This should set your head set to default while they are plugged in and go back to your other speakers when they are not.

Comment: some screenshots would be nice here. I know what you're talking about but this would improve the answer a lot. If you lack sufficient rep, just add links to the images and someone should edit it in.

Answer (score 5):

Open audio manager, on right top side there's "Device advanced settings". Click it and check if "Mute the read output device, when a front headphone plugged in" is selected.

Then click on "Connector settings", in my version (6.0.1.6194) it's the yellow button under the device advanced settings, and check that "Disable front panel jack detection" is **not** checked.

If it still doesn't work check if you have headphones connector on the speakers and use that instead, that should mute the speakers.

Comment: There is no "Devide Advanced Settings" in my realtek driver software. Someone has exactly same problem please check this http://www.vistax64.com/sound-audio/195635-how-can-i-enable-advanced-settings-realtek-hd-audio-manager.html

Comment: According to this: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/drivers/332294-realtek-manager-missing-options.html you can check Bios and try to set HD audio to Enabled, then install drivers again. I think your MB should have this setting in Bios. Other than that I suggest you contact Realtek or MB manufacturer.

Comment: It is enabled in bios setup and i reinstalled driver again but no luck. I asked question in sapphire forum now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I found it on some other forum and it worked for me, 
Check with  volume settings.

1. Right click on the speaker icon in taskbar and select volume control options.
2. put a check mark on "All devices currently playing sound".
3. Make sure you have "The default communication device unchecked".
4. place a check mark on both speakers and headphones.

Comment: This led me to fix my problem, only, I **checked** "The default communication device" and **unchecked** everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have this on my laptop, too.

Right-click on the speaker symbol, choose playback devices and select headphones (might only be there if headphones are inserted) and click on use as standard.

The exact wording might vary, since I only have a German version of windows 7 installed.

Comment: Does not eppear my headphone device in playback devices  When i plug in my headphone to front jacks

Comment: Strange, was the only explanation I could give. My Laptop will always show the headphones and speakers as two different devices and when I plug in my usb audio card others appear. It also only happended since Windows 7 (maybe Vista, skipped that one), not XP - IMO no reason for a down vote though

Comment: I have not down vote you so someone have a reason to down vote you

Answer (score -1):

Plun and unplug the 3.5mm jack many times from both mike and headphones ...it worked for me after I plug/unplug 8 times .